# How to create cropping tool like QuickPic app in android ?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-imageview, crop, pinchzoom

How to create cropping tool like [QuickPic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alensw.PicFolder) app in android where we can move and zoom the image to be cropped?

We need to be able to move the image as well as the cropping frame. Do we need to use canvas to implement this?

Or can we move an object on the other? Any suggestions or links on how to start on this will be praised.

I have used [android-crop](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop)  library but did not get what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the camera Intent Cropping action. If the user device does not support the cropping Intent, they will see an error message. Inside the "try" block, launch the Intent as follows:

```
        //call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not support it)
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP"); 
    //indicate image type and Uri
cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
    //set crop properties
cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    //indicate aspect of desired crop
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    //indicate output X and Y
cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
    //retrieve data on return
cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
```

[You can refer to this link for more details.](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/capture-and-crop-an-image-with-the-device-camera--mobile-11458)